# R is the encoding readLines uses dependent on any meta-information of the .txt file?

Tags: r, text-parsing, file-read

I am trying to read a given set of files which contain characters like "à". So I use the following code to read the file:

```
readLines(con = file.path("C:\\myFolder", "testFile.txt"), encoding = "UTF-8")
```

Now instead of getting an 'à', I get as output "\xe1". So when I remove all content of the .txt file except for this specific letter and a newline, readelines produces "\xe1" as output. Then I created a new file with the same file content, to create a reproducible example. I called it "testFile2.txt". However when I try:

```
readLines(con = file.path("C:\\myFolder", "testFile.txt", "testFile2.txt"), encoding = "UTF-8")
```

I get the expected output of "à". I tried manually retyping the content of the file, resaving both files under a different name in a different folder. But whatever I try, the 2 files with seemingly different content produce different outputs in readLines. Is there any meta-information somehow attached to the files that could be causing this?

I use notepad++ to manipulate the files.

edit: readr::guess_encoding was a good suggestion. I got for the file that worked:
  encoding confidence
1    UTF-8        0.8
2  GB18030        0.1
3     Big5        0.1
And for the file that gave problems:
  encoding confidence
1    UTF-8       0.15
So there does indeed to seem to be an encoding problem

edit 2: and I got my answer, the file was saved in ANSI instead of in UTF-8. So notepad++ of course kept it in that format regardless of how much a moved or renamed it. And when I made a new file to get a reproducible example, it saved that automatically in UTF-8, causing the differences in output when reading the files. Even though the content in notepad++ showed as the same.

Comment: You need to find out what encoding was used to save the file. Only the program that saved it knows for certain, but `readr::guess_encoding` might be able to help. There is no encoding information attached to the file.

Comment: Thanks! This gave me at least another indication that there is a difference. I put the results in my main post

Comment: The problem is solved! @RichardTelford if you add this as an answer I'll upvote and accept it. Either way you have my gratitude.